# What are the differences between competitive equilibrium vs general equilibrium vs market equilibrium?

Tags: microeconomics

Explain what is a competitive equilibrium, general equilibrium and market equilibrium.
What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

Competitive equilibrium is an equilibrium in a competitive market.

Market equilibrium is just generic equilibrium in any market competitive or not.

General equilibrium is equilibrium not just in a single market but also equilibrium  in all markets at the same time. For example, in a simple macro model general equilibrium would be reached when there is not just equilibrium in goods and money market individually but also both the money market and goods market equilibria are consistent with each other.